Fileystem API showDirectoryPicker() permanently broken if user doesn't choose a directory in Electron
This issue occurs in the latest version of Electron, but not in Chromium outside of Electron.
The following example code uses the Filesystem API's showDirectoryPicker method to open a directory-picker when a user clicks a button:
async function handleClick() {
    try {
        dirHandle = await window.showDirectoryPicker({startIn: "downloads"});
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

However the following circumstances lead to the directory-picker being permanently broken:

User is inside Downloads already, so doesn't think they need to create/choose a subdirectory
They click Open without making an explicit choice
The directory-picker "closes" with no directory chosen, and dirHandle is null.
The user clicks the button to try again
This call to showDirectoryPicker() throws an AbortError of NotAllowedError: Failed to execute 'showDirectoryPicker' on 'Window': File picker already active.

Any subsequent clicks to open the directory-picker fail with this same NotAllowedError: Failed to execute 'showDirectoryPicker' on 'Window': File picker already active. error.
So my question is:  How can I deactivate, reset, close, delete, resolve, etc., the File Picker, so that it can be opened a second time.  I can't make the dirHandle null since it's already null.  Likewise, the Promise returned by showDirectoryPicker() is already resolved.
Any solution would be very welcome.  There has to be some obvious way to resolve this, because otherwise it would be a massive bug in the Filesystem API.
Alternatively, is there any way to make showDirectoryPicker() just actually pick that starting directory (Downloads in this case)?
Electron vs Chromium
This only appears to be happening in Electron.  In normal Chromium, this issue cannot occur because instead of giving the user an Open option, it gives them a Select option, and won't allow them not to select a directory.

Alternatively, is there any way to make showDirectoryPicker() just actually pick that starting directory (Downloads in this case)? <- No - this would be a security vulnerability.

so that it can be opened a second time the first thing that comes to mind is doing document.reload();

Which browser are you using? Have you tried a different one? It could very well be a bug in this experimental feature

Ach, sure enough, the issue isn't happening in native chromium, only in the version of chromium that my electron app is opening.  In desktop chromium it won't let you not select a directory.  Updating question...

This turned out to be an Electron issue caused by every version of Electron later than 31.2.1.  I'll open a ticket there, and add an answer here about switching to Electron v31.2

This turned out to be an Electron-specific Issue.  Luckily, one of the Electron engineers has pushed a fix that allows you to catch if a user tries to select a protected System directory.  Better yet, the Electron implementation now lets the developer choose to offer the user the option to override the restriction and specify one of these directories, such as Desktop, Documents, Downloads, etc.
The fix is documented in the Electron Documentation.
In short, you just need to make sure to include dialog and session from electron at the top of main.js:
const { app, dialog, BrowserWindow, session } = require('electron')

and then add code like the following into your createWindow() function:
session.defaultSession.on('file-system-access-restricted', async (e, details, callback) => {
    const { origin, path } = details
    const { response } = await dialog.showMessageBox({
        message: `Are you sure you want ${origin} to open restricted path ${path}?`,
        title: 'File System Access Restricted',
        buttons: ['Choose a different folder', 'Allow', 'Cancel'],
        cancelId: 2
    })

    if (response === 0) {
        callback('tryAgain')
    } else if (response === 1) {
        callback('allow')
    } else {
        callback('deny')
    }
})

This will prompt the user with a dialog box if they try and pick a protected directory, and give them the option to "Choose a different folder", "Allow" using that directory, or "Cancel".  Even if they click "Cancel", they'll still be able to use the directory-picker again, unlike before.
